# Remove quotes from MongoDB field

Tags: mongodb, numbers, quotes

I have a MongoDB collection with many records like this

```
{ 
"_id" : "500cecd97f3b198ba7aceea3",
        "startDate" : NumberLong("1343023785531"),
        "user_id" : "soggettoDGcfe",
        "app_source" : "Diary",
        "measuredValue":120,
}
```

The problem is that due to a bug of an application, there are hundreds of records with the field "measuredValue" as a string:

```
{ 
"_id" : "ab0cecd97f3176eba7aceea3",
        "startDate" : NumberLong("1343023785531"),
        "user_id" : "soggettoDGcfe",
        "app_source" : "Diary",
        "measuredValue":"76.0",
}
```

So when i try to run some queries to check if the value is bigger than something, the record is not returned. With a query i was able to correct some records one by one

```
db.OBSERVABLEPARAMETER.update({_id:"500cecd97f3b198ba7aceea3"},{$set:{measuredValue:76}});
```

but they are hundreds!
How can i update all of them rapidly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the values are the same (that is "76.0"), then you simply do something like :

```
db.OBSERVABLEPARAMETER.update({measuredValue:"76.0"},{$set:{measuredValue:76.0}}, {multi:true});
```

If the values are all different strings, then you will have to find the incorrect strings with :

```
c = db.OBSERVABLEPARAMETER;
c.find({measuredValue:{$type: 2}}).forEach(function (r){
    c.update({_id:r._id},{$set:{measuredValue:Number(r.measuredValue)}});
});
```

*If you have a large number of measurements but a limited number of measuredValue, it might be faster to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) to get all the individual values and then update them in batches.*

Comment: it worked too much :) is it possible to modify the measuredValue ONLY for records with the field app_source:"Diary"?

Comment: `db.OBSERVABLEPARAMETER.update({measuredValue:"76.0", "app_source" : "Diary"},{$set:{measuredValue:76.0}}, {multi:true});` or `c.find({measuredValue:{$type: 2}, "app_source" : "Diary"})`

Comment: sorry what i mean is: the function forEach sets the measuredValue to number, but i need to do such only for records with the field app_source equal to "Diary"

Comment: Do you want `c.find({"app_source" : "Diary"}).forEach(function (r){
    c.update({_id:r._id},{$set:{measuredValue:Number(r.measuredValue)}});
});` then ? MongoDb basic query documents are documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#query-document)

Comment: yeah it was a stupid question but i was quite scared because with the previous query i had side effects... now everything works perfectly thank you very much for your help